# ActionController::UnknownFormat with respond_to js for AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am searching for the internet about this topic, but I don't get how AJAX works with rails, I already check the documentation and I just simply don't understand it.

What I know is that AJAX is asynchronous and it just only takes to put this code in the view for make the request: "`remote:true`", the big deal that I don't get it is about this code:

`respond_to :js`

Apparently, it tells the controller that it would respond to Javascript and you have to make a file for whatever you wanna do with JS, my structure of my project is this one:

> View

**New.html.erb:**

```
<p>Imagen de portada</p>

<%= simple_form_for @entries, remote: true do |f| %>   
  <% f.file_field 'input-image' %> 
<% end %> 
<div id="image-entry"></div>
```

**View route:**

`views
   |
    -->admins
        |
         -->entries
                |-->new.html.erb
                |-->new.js.erb`

> Controller

**entries_controller.rb**

```
module Admins
  class EntriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_admin!

    def index
      render 'index'
    end

    def new
      @entries=''
      render 'new'
      respond_to :js
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller route:**

`controllers
   |
    -->admins
        |
         -->entries_controller.erb`

> JS

**new.js.erb**

```
console.log('funciona');

$('#input-image').click(function(){
  $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

**JS route:**

`views
   |
    -->admins
        |
         -->entries
                |-->new.html.erb
                |-->new.js.erb`

> Error

My error in this code is the following:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

So, I have questions about this error and what is the correct name of the file in JS for get the `respond_to` work correctly.

Comment: Having `render :new` is probably throwing off `respond_to :js`. Try passing a more formal and explicit block `respond_to do |f| ... `

Comment: I already try that option, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Answer by Irfan Fadilah on Facebook:**

Your request is not processed by "new" method in EntriesController. The default form method is POST, so Rails will looking for "create" method in you EntriesController.

You can read RESTful routing in Rails Guide for more details.

In order to make your AJAX request to works. Add "create" method in EntriesController and create.js.erb (just write alert("Hello"); or something to test it) in views/entries.